# Multiple Inputs with Vite

Tags: javascript, vite

I'm having multiple inputs when building my app with vite. My config looks like this:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    eslintPlugin()
  ],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        test1: resolve(__dirname, '/test1.html'),
        test2: resolve(__dirname, '/test2.html')
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The output looks like this:

```
dist
|-test1.html
|-test2.html
|-assets
```

What I actually want is something like this:

```
dist
|test1
  |-index.html
|test2
  |-index.html
|-assets
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The build output normally matches the directory structure of the input file, so in your case, you could move those files into the respective directories under the project root directory:

```
my-project/
 |- test1/
 | `- index.html
 `- test2/
   `- index.html
```

Then configure Vite's `build.rollupOptions.input` to point to those files:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  ⋮
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        test1: resolve(__dirname, './test1/index.html'),
        test2: resolve(__dirname, './test2/index.html'),
      },
    },
  },
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-set-output-dir?file=vite.config.js)

Comment: I know about this, but I wonder if it is not possible to instead of doing this "hack" tell vite per code in which directory I want the html to be placed in.
Isn't there any way to do this?

Comment: but how can I build index1.html in the dist folder and index2.html in a different folder (outside the dist)? and can I build ONLY one OR the other, or will both always be built together?

Answer (score 1):

You can use property names to define dest dirs (see [docs](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#input))

```
...
: rollupOptions: {
    input: {
        'test1/index': resolve(__dirname, '/test1.html'),
        'test2/index': resolve(__dirname, '/test2.html')
    }
}
```