# Build a single Vue 3 application with Vite in two different parts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, build, vite

Can I build a single Vue 3 application with Vite in two different parts?

For example: I have a "docs" folder inside "src" and I want to build only it in the "docs" folder in the root (e.g.: npm run build-doc). And the rest of the application (removing the "docs" folder), build normally in the "dist" folder in the root (npm run buid).

So, if I run "npm run doc", I open the application from the "docs" folder. And if I run "npm run preview", it opens the application in the "dist" folder.

In the end, I'd like it to look like this:

> dist/
>
> > *other files*

> doc/
>
> > *doc files only*

The aim of this is to reuse the components of the application to document them without having to duplicate the application, since there is no separate project just for the design system, and also not to make the documentation available in a public environment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Inputs with Vite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365513/multiple-inputs-with-vite)